# MPVolumeViewWirelessRoutesAvailableDidChangeNotification called continuously with different value

Tags: ios, ios11, apple-tv

I have updated my application to iOS 11 SDK and I am experiencing a very weird issue.

In the application I have support for AppleTV playback. I use the notification `MPVolumeViewWirelessRoutesAvailableDidChangeNotification` to monitor when a new wireless route is available / unavailable. After the upgrade at times I am observing almost constant spam of this notification. Even weirder the result for `areWirelessRoutesAvailable` is variating between `YES` and `NO`. My notification handler code looks something like this:

```
- (void)appleAvailableRoutesChanged:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    MPVolumeView* volumeView = (MPVolumeView*)aNotification.object;
    if(volumeView.areWirelessRoutesAvailable)
    {
        [self addAppleTvButtonToNavBar];
    }
    else
    {
        [self removeAppleTvButtonFromNavBar];
    }
}
```

The end result in my application is that the AppleTV button is blinking like crazy and all the other buttons move around to make room for it or to   close the gap when it disappears. I like to add that my code hasn't been changed for a while.

Sample debug output:

```
"MPVolumeViewWirelessRoutesAvailableDidChangeNotification" available NO
"MPVolumeViewWirelessRoutesAvailableDidChangeNotification" available YES
"MPVolumeViewWirelessRoutesAvailableDidChangeNotification" available NO
"MPVolumeViewWirelessRoutesAvailableDidChangeNotification" available YES
"MPVolumeViewWirelessRoutesAvailableDidChangeNotification" available NO
"MPVolumeViewWirelessRoutesAvailableDidChangeNotification" available YES
"MPVolumeViewWirelessRoutesAvailableDidChangeNotification" available NO
"MPVolumeViewWirelessRoutesAvailableDidChangeNotification" available YES
"MPVolumeViewWirelessRoutesAvailableDidChangeNotification" available NO
"MPVolumeViewWirelessRoutesAvailableDidChangeNotification" available YES
"MPVolumeViewWirelessRoutesAvailableDidChangeNotification" available NO
"MPVolumeViewWirelessRoutesAvailableDidChangeNotification" available YES
"MPVolumeViewWirelessRoutesAvailableDidChangeNotification" available NO
"MPVolumeViewWirelessRoutesAvailableDidChangeNotification" available YES
"MPVolumeViewWirelessRoutesAvailableDidChangeNotification" available NO
"MPVolumeViewWirelessRoutesAvailableDidChangeNotification" available YES
"MPVolumeViewWirelessRoutesAvailableDidChangeNotification" available NO
"MPVolumeViewWirelessRoutesAvailableDidChangeNotification" available YES
"MPVolumeViewWirelessRoutesAvailableDidChangeNotification" available NO
"MPVolumeViewWirelessRoutesAvailableDidChangeNotification" available YES
"MPVolumeViewWirelessRoutesAvailableDidChangeNotification" available NO
```

NOTE: I have several working AppleTVs in my network for testing and I am certain that they all are in perfect working order. When I disconnect them from the network everything works fine.

Does anyone experiencing something similar to that.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. The difference is that it is not happening so many times like yours. It is very random. Did you find any solution or workaround to it?

Comment: Still fighting the problem :(.

Comment: I see this notification is now deprecated, did you find a way to replace this?

Comment: Not for now, but thanks for the info, I will check it out.